# How to make an OR statement in python for user choices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

why it always prints the ascending only?

```
if choose=="A" or "a":
    print("Ascending order: " ,Anewlist)
elif choose=="D" or "d":
    print("Descending order: " ,Dnewlist)
elif choose=="B" or "b":
    print("Ascending order: " ,Anewlist)
    print("Descending order: " ,Dnewlist)
else:
    print("try again")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the equality test on the other side of the `or` command too:

```
if choose == "A" or choose == "a":
    print("Ascending order: ", Anewlist)
```

Alternatively, make the `choose` variable uppercase:

```
if choose.upper() == "A":
    print("Ascending order: ", Anewlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
if choose == "A" or choose == "a":
```

Or:

```
if choose in ("A", "a"):
```